# tkinter event.x executes another function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have function, which is helping me to scroll canvas by left button press and move. Everything works good.

But when I added another function (lets say it is func `B`, I am do not write func `B` code here because it is pretty large and have some dependencies to be executed), which uses `exent.x` and `y` - after executing they automatically execute in the func above and as a result drag my screen to the begining of the canvas. I tried to create another function (deleted func `B`) and use there `event.x` and `y` and got same problem.

If I remove one of functions which uses `event.x` and `y` everything works great, but if I write 2 functions which use `event.x` and `y` they dragging my screen in wrong way.

How could I use `event.x` and `y` without them executing in other functions which use `event.x` and `y`?

**EDIT 2 :**

***Added min code**

```
    from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, main):
        Frame.__init__(self, main)
        self.canvas_width = 64000
        self.canvas_height = 64000
        main.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Execute all functions
        self.center_menu()
        self.grid(self.canvas)

        # Right click menu
        self.rmenu = Menu(self.canvas_frame, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)
        self.rmenu.add_command(label='Create zone', command=self.create_zone_first_step)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", self.popup)

        # Bind
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_zone)
    # End of init function.

    def center_menu(self):
        self.canvas_frame = Frame(main, relief='groove')
        self.canvas_frame.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.canvas_frame.pack_propagate(True)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.canvas_frame, bg='bisque', width=750, height=750,highlightthickness=1)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.addtag_all("main_canvas_tag")

    def popup(self, event):
        self.rmenu.tk_popup(event.x_root + 24, event.y_root - 14, entry="0")
        self.coords_1 = [event.x, event.y]


    def create_zone_first_step(self):
        self.from_x = self.coords_1[0]
        self.from_y = self.coords_1[1]
        # for checking
        self.FIRST_COORDS_CREATED = True


    def create_zone(self, event):
        if self.FIRST_COORDS_CREATED == True:
            self.zone = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.from_x, self.from_y, event.x, event.y)
            self.FIRST_COORDS_CREATED = False

    def grid(self, canvas):
        for l in range(0, self.canvas_width, 10):
            canvas.create_line([(l, 0), (l, self.canvas_width)], fill='#d9d9d9')
        for l in range(0, self.canvas_height, 10):
            canvas.create_line([(0, l), (self.canvas_height, l)], fill='#d9d9d9')

    def scroll_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def scroll_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Tk()
    main.state('zoomed') # open window in full screen
    main.title('My insane warehouse')
    # Eliciting classes
    Main(main)
    main.mainloop()
```

***functions description :***

1. 'Сenter menu` is the frame with canvas
2. `Grid` is painting grid on the canvas.
3. `Scroll` functions are helping user to drag canvas by clicking and moving mouse.
4. `create_zone_first_step` is remembering coords where user clicked when popup appears.
5. `create_zone` is creating rectangle when you left click somewhere

***What you sould do to see the problem:***

1. Open the window and rightclick on canvas, 'add zone' and click somewhere on canvas (without dragging canvas!). It works ok and creating rectangle (zone)
2. But if you drag canvas it will move you "to the begining of the canvas". If we will remove `scroll_ functions` or `create_zone` function it will not move screen 'to the begining'

And the problem is that I need to create rectangle this way, but this inapproproate screen movement bother me to realize my idea.

Sorry for my 'unappreciated' explanations.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to even be able to guess at what's going wrong in your code.

Comment: @jasonharper I edited my question, please take a look

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited my question. Now there is only the needed min of the code. Please take a look

Comment: @BryanOakley check event.x in self.canvas.create_rectangle... It is remembering the last clicked place after creating rectangle and next time I try to scroll canvas it returns me to this remembered place..

Comment: I get errors when I run. Also, why do I need to manually create a "zone"? For the purpose of trying to reproduce this problem, that seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @BryanOakley because creating it by mouse is fast and easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (or at least part of the problem) is that you are trying to bind two different functions to a single event. `<ButtonPress-1>` and `<Button-1>` are the same event. So, when you do `self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_zone)`, that removes the original binding and replaces it with a new binding.

This can be easily demonstrated with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def callback1(event):
    print("callback 1")
def callback2(event):
    print("callback 2")
root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", callback1)
root.bind("<Button-1>", callback2)
root.mainloop()
```

When you run the above code and click around in the window you'll see that only `callback2` is ever called.

Instead of trying to do two separate bindings, you need to have one binding to a function that is smart enough to know when it's supposed to call `scroll_start` and when it's supposed to call `create_zone`.

Another solution would be to temporarily assign a binding when you are in "create a zone" mode, an then revert back to the "scroll start" binding otherwise.